# How does dbt handle models for summarizing data?

Tags: dbt

I use snowflake dynamic tables.  I frequently use them to summarize data.  I see nothing in the dbt tools that address a table materialization for summarized data.  Querying snowflake dynamic tables are lightning fast and up to date based on your desired refresh frequency.  How would dbt be used to produce the same functionality?

Comment: Dbt supports dynamic tables https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/snowflake-configs